# Checking out a proof via induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, fibonacci-numbers

I'm trying to do a proof on fibonacci numbers by induction, and I have an answer but I'm not sure its acceptable.

I'm trying to prove $F_n < 2^n$

My base case at 1 is $F_1 = 1; 2^1 = 2$ therefore checks out

My inductive hypothesis: $F_k < 2^k;   1 \le k \le n$

And inductive step: $F_{k+1} < 2^{k+1}$

I know $F_k = F_{k-1} + F_{k-2}$, so I substitute that into my I.S.

> $F_k + F_{k-1} < 2^{k+1}$

We know the L.H.S is less than or equal to $2F_k$, and $2^{k+1} = 2^k 2$

we can conclude that $F_k + F_{k-1} < 2^{k+1}$ from the above statement.
This is because the above statement is true, and it is shown the L.H.S is less than that of our statement

Comment: this is correct

Comment: You also have to check the base case $F_2$, since the Fibonacci sequence is defined by a linear recurrence relation of order $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right and the proof is correct. Here is how I would write this up to clean up the proof text.

We would like to prove that $$F_n < 2^n \quad \forall n \ge 1.$$ Proceed by Mathematical Induction on $n$.

For the base case, note that
$$
F_1 = 1 < 2 = 2^1,
$$
hence $F_1 < 2^1$ and the statement holds for $n = 1$.

For the inductive step, assume that the claim is true for all $1 \le k \le n$, and let us prove that $F_{n+1} < 2^{n+1}$.

Notice that
$$
\begin{split}
F_{n+1}
   &= F_n + F_{n-1} \quad \text{by the Fibonacci recurrence} \\
   &< 2F_n          \quad \text{since Fibonacci numbers are an increasing sequence} \\
   &< 2 \cdot 2^n   \quad \text{by the Inductive Hypothesis} \\
   &= 2^{n+1}.
\end{split}
$$
Hence, $F_{n+1} < 2^{n+1}$ as desired.

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

Correct .. but as @Bernard says you need to check $F_2$ in addition to $F_1$, and I would also spell out this part a bit better:

$F_{k+1} = F_k + F_{k-1} < 2^k + 2^{k-1} < 2^k + 2^ k = 2*2^k = 2^{k+1}$